# compare two tables or textfiles and output the difference with linenumber and column

Tags: java, ms-access, logging, compare, winmerge

Hi i'm searching for a solution how i can compare two textfiles or two mdb(Access) tables.

**either:**
connect with java to a mdb database and find differences with a output file where it will logged the colums and line numbers.

**or:**
a software with the function.

** I have tested it with WinMerge after i exported it from Access to a textfile.
The problem is that the databaes tables are very big(10mb as textfile). If i create a report this will be to big and confused.*

Have somebody a other idea how i can make this?

Thanks

Comment: You can compare tables using SQL, and do what you wish with the results.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "differences"? Are you looking for differences in Data, or differences in Structure?

If you're looking for differences in Data, you could just use queries, as Overmind suggests:

  SELECT * FROM Table1 T1 LEFT OUTER JOIN Table2 T2 ON (T1.Field1=T2.Field1 AND T1.Field2=T2.Field2) WHERE (T2.Field2 IS NULL OR T2.Field1 IS NULL)

Something along those lines would show you all records in Table1 where the same values DO NOT EXIST in those fields in Table2.

Comment: thats a good idea to make this with SQL statements. Do you know the command what i can use if the tables have every time other columns?
It should compare two tables completly. Thank you